# Scala: split string via pattern matching

Tags: string, scala, split, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Is it possible to split string into lexems somehow like

```
"user@domain.com" match {
    case name :: "@" :: domain :: "." :: zone => doSmth(name, domain, zone)
}
```

In other words, on the same manner as lists...

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it, but I can explain why your example doesn't work.  Essentially what you have is a matcher for a list of Strings because the [`::` case class](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L356), aka "cons" operator, builds a list out of elements.  What you need is a case class which accepts two lists and concatenates them, much like the `:::` operator (but unfortunately there is not a `:::` case class as with cons).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Scala's [Regex](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) functionality.

I found an [email regex on this site](http://blog.trojanhunter.com/2012/09/26/the-best-regex-to-validate-an-email-address/), feel free to use another one if this doesn't suit you:

```
[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

The first thing we have to do is add parentheses around groups:

```
([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+)@([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})
```

With this we have three groups: the part before the `@`, between `@` and `.`, and finally the TLD.

Now we can create a Scala regex from it and then use Scala's [pattern matching unapply](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112) to get the groups from the Regex bound to variables:

```
val Email = """([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+)@([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})""".r
Email: scala.util.matching.Regex = ([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+)@([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+)\.([a-zA-Z]    {2,4})


"user@domain.com" match {
    case Email(name, domain, zone) =>
       println(name)
       println(domain)
       println(zone)
}

// user
// domain
// com
```

Comment: +1 This is easily one of the nicest ways I've seen a language handle regexes. Far nicer than the alternative in a lot of languages, forcing you to manually access a `groups` object and find the right match by index or name. Good answer.

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's possible to pattern match a `String`s by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
val s"$user@$domain.$zone" = "user@domain.com"
// user: String = "user"
// domain: String = "domain"
// zone: String = "com"
```

---

If you are expecting malformed inputs, you can also use a match statement:

```
"user@domain.com" match {
  case s"$user@$domain.$zone" => Some(user, domain, zone)
  case _                      => None
}
// Option[(String, String, String)] = Some(("user", "domain", "com"))
```

Answer (score 3):

In general regex is horribly inefficient, so wouldn't advise.

You CAN do it using Scala pattern matching by calling .toList on your string to turn it into List[Char].  Then your parts `name`, `domain` and `zone` will also be List[Char], to turn them back into Strings use .mkString. Though I'm not sure how efficient this is.

I have benchmarked using basic string operations (like substring, indexOf, etc) for various use cases vs regex and regex is usually an order or two slower.  And of course regex is hideously unreadible.

UPDATE: The best thing to do is to use Parsers, either the native Scala ones, or Parboiled2

Comment: Whaaat? Are you rebuilding the regex each time? The point of regexes is that they create 'machines' that can be matched against strings very efficiently.  Also, using regexes for very small checks doesn't make sense, but for more complex matches, I would expect great efficiency savings, especially as the number if inputs passed through grows.

Comment: @KenoguLabz no the regex construction is outside the benchmark.  When I last went to the Scala eXchange conference, I saw a talk that claimed using parsers (or native Scala `StringOps`) is generally 100 to 1000 times faster.  Obviously if a regex is built badly the speed difference can be even greater (lookup backtracking http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  My own benchmarks are generally performed on real data consisting of billions of records.

Comment: @samthebest I am very much interested in this as I find regex as a language unmaintainable. How would [scala Parsers](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) be superior to compiled regex automatons? how certain are you at this, or can you elaborate at what scenarios? bare bones `StringOps` of course is too low level to maintain code with... not likely a good option for more than those cases where a specific method fits your small ad-hoc need. Care to elaborate here and/or in the answer?

Comment: @matt Three main benefits to using parsers are IMO (a) option to use either regex style syntax or full name version, e.g. `zeroOrMore` or `+`, which improves readability, (b) static full typing, e.g. `+` gives a `List` which you can then map, tranform etc, also means IDEs will syntax highlight it (c) parboiled2 is part macro based, and compiled, so can be substantially faster than regex.  https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#example

Comment: Thanks, those advantages are clear to begin with, to me. But I find these to address the speed aspect:
https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#parboiled2-vs-scala-parser-combinators
https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#parboiled2-vs-regular-expressions. If only they could be trusted, as I seem to recall seeing people say parboiled is slow.